# The flashdata delayed to appear including the process in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, crud

The problem is, every time i delete data from my database the flashdata delayed to show, including the process. When I try to visit to another page and then come back the flashdata appear and the data that i deleted gone. When i work on localhost its fine but when I uploaded into website hosting it is all happen.

My controller

```
public function deleting_highlight($id){
    if($this->session->userdata('level') === '2'){
        $this->highlight_model->delete_highlight($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('deleting_highlight', 'Highlight berhasil dihapus');
        redirect('highlights/index');
    }else{
        redirect('home');
    }      
}
```

my model

```
 public function delete_highlight($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('highlights');
    return TRUE;
}
```

and the view

```
   <div class="container text-center">
       <div class="intro">
       <?php foreach($highlights as $highlight ):?>
           <h1><?= $highlight->head?></h1>
           <h3><?= $highlight->text?></h3>
           <h5><?= $highlight->kecamatan?></h5>
           <p><?= $highlight->kelurahan?></p>
           <small><?= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($highlight->date))?></small>                        
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer">
       <?= form_open('highlights/deleting_highlight/'. $highlight->id);?> 
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" title="Edit" href="<?= base_url('highlights/editing_highlight/'. $highlight->id)?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" title="Hapus" onclick="return confirm('Yakin hapus data?')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>                                
       </form> 
   </div> 
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Please, help me to solve this.. thks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your conditions are not met that is why it is behaving as such.

```
CONTROLLER
public function deleting_highlight($id){
    if($this->session->userdata('level') == '2'){
      $del = $this->highlight_model->delete_highlight($id);
      if($del){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('deleting_highlight', 'Highlight berhasil dihapus');
                redirect('highlights/index');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('deleting_highlight', 'Delete Unsuccesful');
                redirect('highlights/index');
    } else {
        redirect('home');
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
public function delete_highlight($id){
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$del = $this->db->delete('highlights');
return $del;
}
```

VIEW

```
<?= form_open('highlights/deleting_highlight/'. $highlight->id);?> 
       <div class="container text-center">
       <div class="intro">
       <?php foreach($highlights as $highlight ) {?>
           <h1><?= $highlight->head?></h1>
           <h3><?= $highlight->text?></h3>
           <h5><?= $highlight->kecamatan?></h5>
           <p><?= $highlight->kelurahan?></p>
           <small><?= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($highlight->date))?></small>                        
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" title="Edit" href="<?= base_url('highlights/editing_highlight/'. $highlight->id)?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" title="Hapus" onclick="return confirm('Yakin hapus data?')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>                                
       </div>      
       <?php } ?>
   <?= form_close(); ?>
```

Just a few minor changes:

- 1) Comparison check from === to == so it isn't strict
- 2) An extra
  flashdata has been added for you to check if the delete was
  successful or not
- 3) your delete model will return a value, this is
  then checked before setting the flashdata
- 4) Your model delete query
  has been given an variable and that is returned.
- 5) Your form is
  closed with proper syntax